# C++, SFML - Buttons: how to make button that store pointer to method of other class?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, button, sfml

I am trying to make a little pong game with menu. So I`ve made a Button class, that stores function which i run when button gets clicked.
This is how i try to set function that have to get invoked when i press button. (setOnClickFunction)

```
void MenuState::initializeButtons()
{
    Button* startButton = new Button({ 200.f, 200.f }, { 100.f, 100.f },
        "startButton");
    startButton->setOnClickFunction(startButtonOnClick);
}

void MenuState::startGameButtonOnClick()
{
    std::cout << "startButton\n";
}
```

... and this is how my Button class looks like:

```
class Button : public Drawable, public Transformable
{
protected:
    void  (*onClick)();
public:
    void isClicked(Vector2i mousePos);
    void setOnClickFunction(void (*function)());
};
```

after that i get error:

```
"error C3867: 'MenuState::startGameButtonOnClick': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"
```

//EDIT

This is the code that solved my problem:
//MenuState:

```
void MenuState::initializeButtons()
{
    Button* startButton = new Button({ 200.f, 200.f }, { 100.f, 100.f },
        "startButton");
    startButton->setOnClickFunction(std::bind(&MenuState::startGameButtonOnClick, this));
}
```

//Button class:

```
class Button : public Drawable, public Transformable
{
protected:
    std::function<void()> onClick;
public:
    void isClicked(Vector2i mousePos);
    void setOnClickFunction(std::function<void()> function);
};
```

Comment: `setOnClickFunction` should take `function<void()>`. And use `std::bind` or lambda to bind `this` pointer with `startGameButtonOnClick`: `setOnClickFunction( std::bind(&MenuState::startGameButtonOnClick,this) );`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::function` to store your click function.  There are [plenty of examples here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Also, have a look at `std::unique_ptr` to store your button within your `MenuState`

Comment: I also tried that std::function<void()> before, but now I`ve got error like: argument of type "void (MenuState::*)()" is incompatible wit parameter of type "void (*)()"

Comment: Okay I solved this problem -> used std::function<void()> like wreckgar23 said. Will paste solved code to edited post.